# Can I change the VSCode Icon?

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons

I have both Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio 2017 installed on my machines. VSCode at one time had an orange icon and it was great because I could easily tell them apart but, from what I read, they changed it because people didn't like that it looked slightly like Sublime text. So they went with a blueish color, almost identical to the VS2017 icon.

I'm colorblind so this poses a problem. Apparently VS2017 is more of a dark blue/purple color and VSCode is a lighter blue (again, I can't tell). See below, vscode is on the right, vs2017 on the left. Of course, at this zoom level, vscode also has the missing side on the infinity sign, but that is barely visible on a 4K monitor as a toolbar icon.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to change this icon, if even possible?

Comment: This question is quite a good one. Changing the icon would allow to run different VSCode instances with different configurations while all of them could easily be distinguished by its icon. Something that would reeeeaaaaly be useful.

Comment: @RegisMay that preciselly how I ended up looking at this post. I have multiple projects and every time I either click through them until I find the right instance, or hover and wait for the tooltip that identifies them.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, you should check this repo: https://github.com/dhanishgajjar/vscode-icons
I'm pretty sure you'll find some combinations that work with your color blind situation (There are so many combinations!).

And about how to change it, just right click in the program icon, then properties, then shortcut, then change icon. You could read the complete instructions here: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/change-taskbar-icons-programs-windows-10/

Comment: This does not help as it only changes the icon for the shortcut, however the actual program icon that appears in the taskbar will still be the original.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I loved green logo

Comment: the OS caches the icon, so it takes a while to see the new icon, in task switcher and dock and such